# Postman API get access token

Tags: python, azure, access-token

I am not trying to get an access token to any other website using postman, I am trying to get an access token for the actual Postman website!!

I have a script that I am working to implement for Azure and I need to use postman to send a POST request and download the response body. Based on my research, to be able to use the POST request to download the response body, I need to pass Postman an access token as a parameter for my download function.

This is my auth method to get the access token for postman:

```
def authenticate_postman(api_key, username, password):
    ''' Authenticate into Postman API and get a valid access token
    '''
    global access_token
    url = "https://api.postman.com/oauth/token"

    headers = {
        "X-Api-Key": api_key,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }

    data = {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(response.json())
        raise Exception("Failed to authenticate. HTTP Error {}".format(response.status_code))

    access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
    return access_token
```

`api_key`, `username`, `password` come from `os.environ`

I get this error:

```
{'error': {'name': 'notFound', 'message': 'Requested resource not found'}}
```

I am not sure why it doesn't work or how I can fix this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to authenticate with Postman's `OAuth 2.0 API`, which needs to provide valid credentials to obtain an access token.

> The error message suggests that the API endpoint you are trying to access is not found, which could mean that the URL you are using is incorrect.

Check the URL of the API endpoint. It should be "https://api.postman.com/oauth2/token" instead of "https://api.postman.com/oauth/token". The "/oauth2" path is important and must be included.

Verify that your `API key` is valid and has the necessary permissions to access the `OAuth 2.0 API`. You can check this by logging into your Postman account and going to the "API Keys" section.

Check that the `credentials` you are using are correct and match the account associated with the API key.

If you are still having issues, try using a tool like cURL or the Postman app to manually send the API request and inspect the response.

```py
import json
import requests

AUTHORITY_HOST = "login.windows.net"
TENANT_ID      = < tenant id >
CLIENT_ID      = < client id >
CLIENT_SECRET  = < client secret >
VAULT          = 'MyVault'

data = { "grant_type" : "client_credentials", 
        "client_id" : CLIENT_ID, 
        "client_secret" : CLIENT_SECRET, 
        "resource" : "https://vault.azure.net"
    }

secrets = [( "i_like_pie", "8a7680a2cf5e4d539494aa0ce265297" )]

headers = { "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }

r = requests.post("https://login.windows.net/{}/oauth2/token".format(TENANT_ID), data=data, headers=headers)
access_token = r.json()['access_token']

for secret, secret_id in secrets.iteritems():

    headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer {}".format(access_token) }
    r = requests.get('https://{}.vault.azure.net/secrets/{}/{}?api-version=2015-06-01'.format(VAULT, secret, secret_id), headers=headers)

    print('##### {} #####'.format(secret))
    print(r.json())
    print('')
```

For further information refer the below Docs.

[API Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/authentication-requests-and-responses?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Thanks to [@Vikram Kone](https://github.com/vikramkone/toolbox/blob/master/AzureKeyVaultSDK.py)